# Python substring the text between two text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following string and want out put `1112223332`

`The setNumber, 1112223332 was not found`

I am trying to use below but its not giving the my desired output

```
STRING.find("setNumber,: (\w+)", STRING)
```

is there anyway to get the result `1112223332`

Comment: You need to use the `re` module to search for a regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.find()` searches for exact matches, not regular expressions.

Use `re.search()`

```
import re

string = "The setNumber, 1112223332 was not found"
match = re.search(r"setNumber, (\d+)", string)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
inp = "The setNumber, 1112223332 was not found"
matches = re.findall(r'\bsetNumber, (\w+)', inp)
print(matches)  # ['1112223332']
```